# Mountain Lion reinstall failure

Tags: macos, install, internet-recovery

I am trying to fix a Macbook Pro from around 2012/2013, the hard drive failed so I replaced it with a Sandisk 120GB SSD and I am trying to reinstall OS X Mountain Lion using Internet recovery.

Here's what I've done: installed SSD, connected power, Ethernet, booted into Internet Recovery using Command+R, formatted the disk using Disk Utility (Mac os Extended - Journaled), started re-install.

I starts out just fine:

[image: Reinstall started]

But then it gets the bar filled, stalls there for long time and the it 
pops up with the message:

[image: Reinstall Error]

The error message is in Danish and translates to something like: "Can’t download the additional components needed to install Mac OS X". Does anybody know how to get fix this installation issue?

**Edit: Attempted suggestion 3) by Keith**

Using a Macbook Pro with OS Sierra I got an USB Boot disk created, ran disk utility and started the install, which after about half an hour stopped the installation with the message:

[image]

Which translates to something along the lines of "The installer payload failed signature check".

**Edit: Hardware issue and solution**

Turns out that something was wrong with the SATA/IR cable connecting the drive to the logic board. Installation succeeded when installing onto the harddrive connected via USB.

I then purchased a caddy and replaced the optical drive with the SSD inside the caddy. It now runs MacOS Sierra just fine.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/90458/88313) and see if it helps.

Comment: @fsb as I understand the answer you are referring to then the solution would be to use a functioning Mac, with Mountain Lion installed, to create a USB installer instead of using internet recovery. Correct? I don't have access to another Mac unfortunately.

Comment: @safl If you're still around, you should post your "edit" as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that for some Macbook Pros, it is common for the internal SATA cable to start malfunctioning over time. The errors I experienced does not give a clear indication that this is the case but if others come across this thread and experience spurious installation errors then here are three different ways of getting a Macbook Pro running again:

1. Connect hard drive via USB/SATA, cost ~12$ and easy but cumbersome to
   have the drive dangling around, so mostly useful for debugging and
   determining that it is the internal SATA cable that is
   malfunctioning.
2. Connect hard drive via optical drive caddy, cost ~12$, installation
   guide
   https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+Dual+Hard+Drive/8529
3. Replace the internal SATA cable, cost ~40$, installation
   guide:
   https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Hard+Drive+Cable+Replacement/10379

Answer (score 2):

### Quick solution:

1. Install from USB drive with own power supply, seems not to work using usb stick.

### Same solution with more text:

I had same issue on imac from mid 2009 with os x Lion. I was not able to boot from USB stick. I tried diffrent usb memory sticks but none work. However it worked with a harddrive with external power source. Then I was able to boot from USB.

I also found a lot of video guides with instructions on how to install the osx on the drives. Most of the guides had links to thiere own High sierra release (seems like this is the best option to use since it still gets updates and work with old macs). They also warned about other site might have virus in there releases, this made me got worried so I have my own release here(just joking its from the official apple site):
http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2019/cert/061-39476-20191023-48f365f4-0015-4c41-9f44-39d3d2aca067/InstallOS.dmg  (not sure why they didn't link to it). It also possible to get form apple store if you haven't removed everything on your disk.

Here are the instructions also:
https://support.apple.com/sv-se/HT208202  (above link is also on the page to high sierra)

Answer (score 0):

You're in a slightly tricky situation if you can't get the internet recovery to work.

I would probably try the following (skip any steps you've tried or can't do):

1. Try the Internet Recovery again using a wired connection
2. Call a nearby Apple store and make an appointment with the Genius Bar/Grove/whatever it's called now to have them install the OS for you (or at least create a bootable USB install drive)
3. Ask a friend/acquaintance at work/school who owns a mac to download the Mountain Lion installer from the app store and use it to create a bootable USB installer drive. You'll need to supply them with a USB drive (8Gb or larger), and possibly buy them a beverage of their choice to say thanks afterwards.

It is possible to create a bootable OSX install usb drive from windows (google "make osx boot usb from windows" for instructions) *if* you have downloaded the installer file, but there's no straightforward way to get the installation file if you haven't already.

If you don't have access to a nearby Apple store, then I think your best bet will be to prod your circle of friends/acquaintances until you find one that owns a Mac, and then solicit their help.

Comment: I used wired connection (ethernet), trying suggestion 3. do you know whether I can install Sierra on a Mac that came with Mountain Lion? I ask since Mountain Lion is not available in the store on the "helper-mac", only Sierra.

Comment: Must admit I don't know re: installing Sierra directly.

My Macs are both first-gen retina MBPs, bought on release in 2012. If I look in the "purchased" tab of the MacOS app store, I can see the Mountain Lion installer and download it. You might try the same approach on your helper mac. You could also try signing into the app store using your own Apple account details on that mac -- even if the helper mac is newer, you may still be able to download it from there. Note that you can't use the search bar -- you have to scroll through the list and find it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check to be sure that the status of the hard drive is "Verified". Here's how to do that.

1. In Recovery Mode, enter Disk Utility.
2. In the left panel, click on the top drive (not the partition).
3. Under S.M.A.R.T status, check to make sure it says "Verified". If not, either the hard drive is bad somehow or it's corrupted and needs to be formatted/erased.

Comment: Thanks for the input, hard drive is fine, it shows up as "Verified". To further test the hardware I installed Xubuntu and it completed without error.